# É possível alterar o css3 da tabela(em JqGrid) para mudar o posicionamento na pagina?

Tags: html, jquery, css3, jqgrid

É possível alterar o posicionamento da tabela na pagina da biblioteca JqGrid?

Quando a tabela do Jqgrid retorna muitos dados, cria uma barra de rolagem na vertical.

Ao descer para visualizar os últimos registros a tabela vai para de trás do menu mas não vai para trás do topo. Somente a tabela, o restante da 'div' vai, como campos de filtragem com 'inpunt' e 'select', esse vão certo para trás do topo.
Ja tentei Z-index no topo. 
Veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<link href="~/Areas/Representantes/Script/consultaentrega/ConsultaEntregaEstilo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br /><br />
<div class="alinaresquerda">

    <center><img src="~/Content/imagem/logo.png" id="recurso" /></center>
    <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-primary">
        <center><h4>CONSULTA ENTREGA</h4></center>
    </div>


    <input type="hidden" id="sessaoRepresentante" value="@ViewBag.representante" />

    <fieldset class="grupo">
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="nome">Representante</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="codigoRepresentante" id="representante"></select>
        </div>
    </fieldset>



    <table id="jqGrid"></table>
    <div id="jqGridPager"></div>
    <hr />


</div>
<br /><br />
<script src="~/Areas/Representantes/Script/consultaentrega/consultaentregalista.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
    var url = "/Representantes/ConsultaEntrega/lista";

$(document).ready(function () {

    //Verifica permissão 
    var recurso = "TELA_REPRESENTANTE_CONSULTA_ENTREGA";
    VerificaPermissao(recurso); 

    var representante = $("#sessaoRepresentante").val();

    if ($("#sessaoRepresentante").val() != "0") {
        $("#representante").prop("disabled", true);
    }

    CarregaRepresentante(representante);    

    var $table = $("#jqGrid");

    $table.jqGrid({
        url: url,
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',  
        postData: {
            representante: function () { return jQuery("#representante option:selected").val(); }         
        }, 
       colModel: [
           { label: 'PEDIDO', name: 'D2_PEDIDO', width: 60 },
           { label: 'DOC', name: 'F2_DOC', width: 80 },
           { label: 'SERIE', name: 'F2_SERIE', width: 40 },
           { label: 'CLIENTE', name: 'F2_CLIENTE', width: 60 },
           { label: 'LOJA', name: 'F2_LOJA', width: 50 },
           { label: 'ZRAZAO', name: 'F2_ZRAZAO', width: 250 },
           { label: 'CHVNFE', name: 'F2_CHVNFE', width: 320 },
           { label: 'CODTRA', name: 'CODTRA', width: 60},
           { label: 'NOMETRA', name: 'NOMETRA', width: 120 },
           { label: 'NOMERED', name: 'NOMERED', width: 80 },
           { label: 'EMISSAO', name: 'F2_EMISSAO', width: 80 },
           { label: 'ZDTSAID', name: 'F2_ZDTSAID', width: 80 },
           { label: 'GWU_DTPENT', name: 'GWU_DTPENT', width: 80 },
           { label: 'GWU_DTENT', name: 'GWU_DTENT', width: 80 }


        ],

         viewrecords: true,
            rowNum: 20,
            rowList: [20, 40, 100],
            height: "auto",
            //height: 400,
            emptyrecords: "Nenhum Registro",
            loadtext: "Buscando e carregando...",
            //rowNum: 20,
            pager: "#jqGridPager",
            loadonce: true

    });


    $('select#representante').on("change", function () {

        var id = $("#representante").val();
        $("#nome").val('');
        $("#jqGrid").setGridParam({ datatype: 'json', page: 1 }).trigger('reloadGrid');
    });


    function CarregaRepresentante(representante) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Gerenciamento/UsuarioExterno/SelecionarRepresentante",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {

                $("#representante").empty();

                if (representante == 0) {
                    $("#representante").append('<option value="" disabled selected hidden>Selecione...</option>');
                }

                $.each(data, function (i, element) {
                    if (representante > 0) {
                        if (representante == element.codigoRepresentante) {
                            $("#representante").append('<option  value=' + element.codigoRepresentante + ' selected >' + element.nome + '</option>');
                        }
                    }
                    $("#representante").append('<option value=' + element.codigoRepresentante + '>' + element.nome + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    }



});
```

CSS do topo (gerado pelo framework):

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

Comment: Danielle coloque o CSS que contenha a classe do Topo. Seu problema está lá muito provavelmente.

Comment: esse topo {<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">} foi gerado pelo framework  asp.net em um arquivo  navbar.less com mais de 500 linhas. Daí não sei se é legal postar ele pelo tamanho. Mas coloquei na Pergunta o CSS e Classe que eu acho que ele chama.

Comment: Em `.navbar-fixed-top` coloque `position:relative` e `z-index: 1031` para fazer um teste. Basicamente um elemento que não tenha um position definido não vai reconhecer o z-index. Se responder me fala que eu dou uma resposta mais detalhada.

Comment: Obrigada Hugo, eu consegui depois de muito mexer .. Alteirei direto no arquivo ui.jqgrid.css o z-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com eu imaginava. Alterei na biblioteca. 
No arquivo ui.jqgrid.css eu alterei para :

```
.ui-jqgrid {
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    z-index: 0;  // de 1 para 0
}
```